# Extra Null Rows in Hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hql, cloudera-cdh

My project involves migrating data from an SQL database to HDFS, then creating Hive tables linking the data files to the tables. I am doing the migration manually by exporting the contents of the database to CSV files on my local machine, I'm copying these over to the hadoop edgenode using winSCP. There I am running the following commands:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/cloudera/project/database/table
```

followed by

```
hadoop fs -put /home/cloudera/project/table.csv /user/cloudera/project/database/table/table.csv
```

finally, I'm running an hql script called from the same shell script file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME 
(
    FIELD_ONE STRING, 
    FIELD_TWO INT,
    ETC STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/project/database/table'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

The problem that arises is that I end up with 70 more rows in HDFS than there were in the SQL database to begin with. I suspect the cause of this problem is that some lines are being truncated (with the remaining part of the line being brought down to the next line). This results in extra rows with completely wrong data.

What could be causing this problem, and is there a workaround to it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of the extra blank new lines in the csv files. Edit the CSV files in any editor (for ex: vi table.csv) and remove the blank lines after the end of data.

Hive table with blank lines in CSV:

`United States   Barbados        130
United States   Qatar   109
Australia       United States   329
Australia       India   310
        NULL    NULL
        NULL    NULL`

Hive table after removing the blank lines in CSV:

`United States   Barbados        130
United States   Qatar   109
Australia       United States   329
Australia       India   310`

The best approach is to use "Sqoop" to import the data from SQL database to Hive. sqoop will handle the schema and you can load the data incrementally as well.
Refer to: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive

Comment: I will try this out! However, not all the extra rows in Hive are NULL. Some have incorrect information as well.

Comment: Sure, you can also add LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' clause to the table definition if still the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is related to Which database you are using to import data? If you are using DB2 database then below parameter will resolve your issue.

```
sqoop import -D db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3
```